Voltage Input Biasing on NMOS in CMOS Comparator
As part of my discrete transistor computer project, I want to keep the theme with the clock module. It took a little research, but I think I have some grasp on how OpAmps work. However, I found a small issue: the threshold voltage means that I can't compare voltages below ~1.5V. This issue is just small because I don't need to compare voltages below 1.5V for the square wave generator I threw together (essentially a bootleg 555 timer).
Even though it isn't really an issue for my purposes, I'm still curious for a solution. I know I could bias the NMOS inputs with the threshold voltage, but that's just one part of the solution. How could I translate a 0-5V signal into a Vth-5V signal?
Also, if there's an issue with the design, please let me know, I'm learning as I go.
The comparator design I'm using:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The clock generator (sorry it's messy, I ran into some issues while setting it up):

simulate this circuit

This is the same problem that all comparator/opamp inputs have.

When you need to handle input voltages near ground, but not near the positive supply, then just invert everything and use P-channel MOSFETs for the inputs. (This is what the common LM393 does, with BJTs.)

When you need to handle the entire voltage range, i.e., a rail-to-rail inputs, then you either

use two pairs of complementary N/P input transistors (which can lead to an offset voltage discontinuity where the N-channel range and the P-channel range meet (this is not a problem for digital signals)), or
use a charge pump to generate a bias voltage that is higher than the supply (which uses more power and can generate noise).



